# Validate ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want to validate my page to prevent HTML Injection attacks.

Some viruses, trojans etc. can detect and inject some code to your web site. And this can cause design of your web site can change or some malicious codes can be injected.

How can I validate my page is really my page that I create from server?

Comment: I don't try anything now. I just want to give some advice about it. I just think to keep my page structure somewhere and check it from there. If you have better idea, please share it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `validateRequest` to `true`, which is default

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And always encode user input:

```
Server.HtmlEncode("<script>unsafe</script>");
```

For more information:

[Request Validation - Preventing Script Attacks](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation)

[HtmlEncode, HtmlDecode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)

Comment: I don't mean just malicious codes. I want to validate my page structure from top to bottom. I don't want anything injected. If you have any experience about malicious programs, you can understand me well. They can inject what they want. But I want to validate my page to inform users.